# Cloning Bitbucket server repo with access tokens

Tags: rest, bitbucket, git-clone, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

I am trying to clone a bitbucket server repo (self-hosted) using access-token however I could not find any documentation on Bitbucket server API. My clone url is ssh based.

Or is there a way to use REST API curl command to clone bitbucket server repos?

Comment: Where are you trying to clone your repo: your local machine? You don't use the Bitbucket API for that, just `git clone <url>`...

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I need to automate that part so I have to add the authentication details for validation in the script.

Comment: Probably the simplest solution is to use an [ssh key](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html) for that, not a PAT you'd use for the API.

Comment: @msanford Is there a way/syntax to automate the validation using ssh keys then?

Comment: What validation do you want to do exactly? (Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56760396/edit) the question and add that?)

Comment: Using a ssh key is simple, but your ssh key typically has write access (unless you create a separate account) whereas your access token can be restricted to reading.

Answer (score 21):

The [official documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/oauth-on-bitbucket-cloud-238027431.html) says that you should:

```
git clone https://x-token-auth:$ACCESS_TOKEN@yourbitbucketserver/...
```

In my experiments with a BitBucket 6.1 server, this does not work and gives HTTP 401 instead. Using ssh with access tokens seems to be entirely unsupported.

What did work was:

```
git -c "http.extraHeader=Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" clone https://yourbitbucketserver/...
```

Comment: changing `x-token-auth` with an actual user name works for me.

Comment: @osexp2003 your comment should be the accepted answer

Comment: not sure what's the issue on our side, but we're keep getting: `URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL` because of the characters inside the `$TOKEN` ...

Comment: Years passed and the `x-token-auth` solution works fine now

Answer (score 0):

To clone over SSH you'll want to use an SSH key, note you can add more than one SSH key to a user account in Bitbucket Server, so you can identify with a specific SSH key if you'd like.

If you like the extra permission control that the Personal Access Tokens give you, you can clone over HTTPS, as our PATs are designed specifically for clone over HTTPS, and authenticating to the REST API using Basic Auth / Bearer token.

For more information see https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/personal-access-tokens-939515499.html

Answer (score 0):

```
git clone -c http.extraHeader='Authorization: Bearer BBDC-xxxxxx' https://bitbucket.example.com/scm/~myusername/my_repo.git
```

Per https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/personal-access-tokens-939515499.html